# Changing Axis on Time Series Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast

I have made a time series from the following dataframe.

```
     Year    Month Demand
1 2010  January   48.5
2 2010 February   46.0
3 2010    March   54.4
4 2010    April   49.8
5 2010      May   48.1
6 2010     June   55.0
```

I use the following to make the ts object:

```
   ts.Monthly.Demand=Monthly.Demand%>%
  select(Demand)%>%
  ts(start=2010,frequency=12)
```

I use the following to make the plot:

```
ts.Monthly.Demand%>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

How can I add the month to the x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `autoplot` returns a `ggplot` object, you can add additional `ggplot` functions to it as you would in any other ggplot workflow. That includes setting the scale, such as with `scale_x_date` and giving date breaks however you like. A couple formatting options to `date_labels`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfortify)

ts1 <- df %>%
  select(Demand) %>%
  ts(start = 2010, frequency = 12)

autoplot(ts1) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%Y")
```

[image]

```r
autoplot(ts1) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B %Y")
```

[image]

```r
autoplot(ts1) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b '%y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Convert to zoo and use `scale_x_yearmon`

```
library(zoo)

z.Monthly.Demand <- as.zoo(ts.Monthly.Demand)
autoplot(z.Monthly.Demand) + scale_x_yearmon() + xlab("")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

or using classic graphics:

```
plot(z.Monthly.Demand)
```

[image: screenshot]